# Change Default Name Given to Symlinks

Tags: 18.04, symbolic-link

I would like to change the name given to any new symlink by default. So if I have a file named "A", the system names the symlink: "Link to A".
But I want to make it "A -Link".
System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: Please let us know which flavor of Ubuntu you are using. Different desktop environments would require different solutions (if possible at all).

Comment: As the tag suggests, my system is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver).